# Try to format a Unix date pattern (%Y-%m-%d) with android kotlin using SimpleDateFormat Class but no result

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, simpledateformat

I am receiving that date patterns from an API and I am trying to parse it with my android app with no clue how to do it any help is appreciated.

I already try a bunch of date libraries and a spend a lot of time with research with no result.

```
And here is simple of the code i am trying :

val simpleFormat = SimpleDateFormat("%Y-%m-%d", Locale.getDefault())
simpleFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
val now: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()!!

Log.d("datedate", simpleFormat.format(now.time).toString())
```

I am receiving the following result %2019-%20-%25

I am seeking a normal date such as `2019-4-25`, for example.

Comment: why don't you read the documentation before you try to use it?

Comment: do you mean the SimpleDateFormat documentation if yes i did and it have nothing to say about the issue i am facing.

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Ok, then what output you want to get as result?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro i am seeking a normal date such as 2019-4-25 for example

Comment: if you have read the documentation, then why are you using that `%`? Also `m` is minute, not month

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes true but this pattern is not java pattern it's a Unix shell date pattern what i am trying to do is parse it to java patterns

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. Show example - what you have as input, and which result you want to get.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko my case is I am using an API that returns the date patterns selected by the user the case is some users are using Unix Shell that uses such patterns but the SimpleDateFormat class can't parse such patterns what I am trying to is parse such patterns to show the right dates o the users.

Comment: **Show an example**

Comment: @MahmoudAziz `SimpleDateFormat`, as you discover when reading the doc, is simply not designed to understand Unix shell date format. You have to make your own formatter.

Comment: i am consuming jira API's where in the create screen there is date fields that the user can select the suitable format for his envirement most users select the normal patterns such as DD-MMM-YYYY or dd-MM-YYYY ... but lstely a user use this pattern %Y-%m-%d wich is a Unix shel pattern in that case when i try to parse this pattern the date is displaying in the wrong format in the field.\

Comment: @Benoit you mean i have to check all the Unix shell pattern and theire equivilent on java patterns and create my own pattens to handle those cases.

Comment: @MahmoudAziz Yes. Alternatively you can write (or search for) a utility class that would convert Unix shell pattern to Java pattern.

Comment: Hi @OleV.v. Sorry for the late response I didn't know about that. and thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix date format strings, for example your `%Y-%m-%d`, follow a completely different system than the format pattern strings used by Java’s `DateTimeFormatter` or the troublesome and outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, such as `yyyy-MM-dd` (the two Java classes on the other hand use quite similar, though not identical format pattern strings).

I think that the first thing you need to decide is whether you want to cover all possible Unix format strings or just the most common ones. The Unix format string language is quite elaborate. It’s easy enough to translate `%Y` to `yyyy`, `%m` to `MM`, etc., and `%%` to just one `%`. You will need to quote any letters that are not preceded by a percent sign in single quotes to tell the Java formatter that they are not pattern letters. For example Unix `%d of %B` should be `dd 'of' MMMM` in Java. Unix also includes `%C` for century, which Java does not support (or only through a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and a homegrown `TemporalField`, you won’t want to bother). POSIX has some three character extensions, `%Ec`, `%EC`, `%Ex`, etc., and you may insert `_`, `-` or `0` between the percent sign and the letter to control the padding. Finally there are differences between GNU and BSD, so you need to decide which you go by.

For translating from Unix to Java you can probably get a long way with regular expressions, but if you do want to cover all cases, I expect that hand coding a parser will be easier in the long run.

### The hack: String.format

`String.format` in Java uses format strings that are a bit similar to those used by Unix `date`. The main difference is that Java has a `t` between the percent sign and the letter: `%Y` in Unix is `%tY` in Java, etc. So insert one:

```
    String unixFormatString = "%Y-%m-%d";
    // Insert 't'
    String javaFormatString = unixFormatString.replaceAll("(%)(\\w)", "$1t$2");

    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Antarctica/Rothera"));

    // We need to pass the datetime to String.format as many times as there are
    // format specifiers in the format string. There cannot be more than half of the
    // length of the string. Passing too many doesn’t harm, so just pass this many.
    Object[] formatArgs = Collections.nCopies(javaFormatString.length() / 2, now).toArray();
    String formattedDateTime = String.format(javaFormatString, formatArgs);
    System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

When I ran this snippet today, I got:

> 2019-01-26

There are very many cases it does not cover, but it covers many of the most common ones.

### Link

[How To Format Date For Display or Use In a Shell Script](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `%` symbol from the date formatter code or change it to the code below. It should display the date properly.

`val simpleFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())`

Comment: I bet you need lowercase `y` and uppercase `M` (if you really want to use the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class).

Comment: Tnx for the answer but the problem is that this pattern is a Unix Shell pattern and i am trying to parse it into java date pattern.

Comment: @MahmoudAziz Can you give example of the exact format you want.

Comment: for example, the API returns this pattern %Y-%m-%d which is not a java pattern what I need is to parse it into java to be able to display the date correctly to the user.

Comment: @MahmoudAziz Please give example like `12 min ago`, `2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700` etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the SimpleDateFormat you specify you how want the output of the date.

In your example you have `%Y-%M-%d` so you will get `%2019-%01-%01`

If you change to `Y-M-d` you get `2019-01-01`

In your code

```
val simpleFormat = SimpleDateFormat("Y-m-d", Locale.getDefault())
```

You can check the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) for further info

Comment: I bet you need lowercase `y` and uppercase `M` (if you really want to use the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class).

Comment: Tnx for the answer but the problem is that this pattern is a Unix Shell pattern and i am trying to parse it into java date pattern